# How can I change this code to make the user enter in both the Month and the Year instead of just stopping at entering in the month?

Tags: java, prompt

I am trying to accomplish this assignment: 
Write a program that prompts the user to enter a year 
and the first three letters of a month’s name (with 
the first letter in uppercase) and displays the number 
of days in the month. REMEMBER to account for leap 
years!

When I run the program, it prompts me to enter in a year. I enter in a random year and then it doesn't do anything else. Can someone help me so that I am able to not only enter in a year, but also a corresponding month?

Here is a sample result:

Enter a year: 
2002
Enter a month (first 3 letters with the first letter in uppercase): 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

My program is here:

```
  package assignment.pkg4;

/**
 *
 * @author David Yang
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DaysOfAMonth {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        // Create a Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt the user to enter a year
        System.out.println("Enter a year: ");

        int year= input.nextInt();

        // Prompt the user to enter the first 3 letters of a month
        System.out.println("Enter a month (first 3 letters with the first letter in uppercase): ");
        String month = input.nextLine();


        if (null != month) switch (month) {
            case "Jan":
            case "Mar":
            case "May":
            case "July":
            case "Aug":
            case "Oct":
            case "Dec":
                System.out.println(month + year + "has 31 days");
                break;
            case "Apr":
            case "Jun":
            case "Sep":
            case "Nov":
                System.out.println(month + year + "has 30 days");
                break;
            case "Feb":
                System.out.println(month + year + "has 28 days");
        }

        if (year % 4 == 0) {
            if ("Feb".equals(month))
                System.out.println(month + year + "has 29 days");
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input.nextInt();` will not take the \n on the line so you need to have one explicitly to remove it.

```
int year= input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
```